# Error in Audio Data Augmentation Script: TypeError in time_stretch function

Tags: python, classification, librosa

I'm working on donateacry-corpus data augmentation script in Python using the librosa library, and I'm encountering a TypeError in the time_stretch function. The script aims to apply various augmentation techniques to audio files, such as adding noise, shifting, and stretching.

```
import wave
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob
import scipy
import soundfile as sf

class AudioAugmentation:
def read_audio_file(self, file_path):
    data, sample_rate = sf.read(file_path)
    return data, sample_rate

def write_audio_file(self, file, data, sample_rate):
    sf.write(file, data, sample_rate)
    
def add_noise(self, data,noise_factor):
    noise = np.random.randn(len(data))
    augmented_data = data + noise_factor * noise
    # Cast back to same data type
    augmented_data = augmented_data.astype(type(data[0]))
    return augmented_data

def shift(self, data):
    y_shift = data.copy()
    timeshift_fac = 0.5 * 2 * (np.random.uniform() - 0.5)  # up to 20% of length
    print("timeshift_fac = ", timeshift_fac)
    start = int(y_shift.shape[0] * timeshift_fac)
    print(start)
    if (start > 0):
        y = np.pad(y_shift,(start,0),mode='constant')[0:y_shift.shape[0]]
    else:
        y = np.pad(y_shift,(0,-start),mode='constant')[0:y_shift.shape[0]]
    return y.T

def stretch(self, y, rate=1):
    input_length = len(data)
    streching = data.copy()
    streching = librosa.effects.time_stretch(streching.astype('float'), 1.1)
    if len(streching) > input_length:
        streching = streching[:input_length]
    else:
        streching = np.pad(streching, (0, max(0, input_length - len(streching))), "constant")
    #data = librosa.effects.time_stretch(data, rate)
    return streching

# Create a new instance from AudioAugmentation class
aa = AudioAugmentation()

#Read and produce augmentation files
list1 = os.listdir("/Users/kphil/Documents/UNUD/Capstone/donateacry_corpus_dataset/tired")
print(list1)

for file in list1:
if not file.startswith('.'):
    print(file)
    data, sr = aa.read_audio_file("/Users/kphil/Documents/UNUD/Capstone/donateacry_corpus_dataset/tired/" + file)
    # aa.plot_time_series(data)
    # Adding noise to sound
    data_noise = aa.add_noise(data,0.005)
    # aa.plot_time_series(data_noise)
    # Shifting the sound
    data_roll = aa.shift(data)
    # aa.plot_time_series(data_roll)
    # Stretching the sound
    data_stretch = aa.stretch(data, 1.1)
    # aa.plot_time_series(data_stretch)
    # Write generated sounds
    aa.write_audio_file('/Users/kphil/Documents/UNUD/Capstone/donateacry_corpus_dataset/output/tired/generated1_' + file, data_noise, sr)
    aa.write_audio_file('/Users/kphil/Documents/UNUD/Capstone/donateacry_corpus_dataset/output/tired/generated2_' + file, data_roll, sr)
    aa.write_audio_file('/Users/kphil/Documents/UNUD/Capstone/donateacry_corpus_dataset/output/tired/generated3_' + file, data_stretch, sr)
```

now it has some error like this:

```
03ADDCFB-354E-416D-BF32-260CF47F7060-1433658024-1.1-f-04-ti.wav
timeshift_fac =  -0.21702319189821973
-12153
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[67], line 13
 10 data_roll = aa.shift(data)
 11 # aa.plot_time_series(data_roll)
 12 # Stretching the sound
---> 13 data_stretch = aa.stretch(data, 1.1)
 14 # aa.plot_time_series(data_stretch)
 15 # Write generated sounds
 16 aa.write_audio_file('/Users/kphil/Documents/UNUD/Capstone/donateacry_corpus_dataset/output/tired/generated1_' + file, data_noise, sr)

Cell In[64], line 31, in AudioAugmentation.stretch(self, y, rate)
 29 input_length = len(data)
 30 streching = data.copy()
---> 31 streching = librosa.effects.time_stretch(streching.astype('float'), 1.1)
 32 if len(streching) > input_length:
 33     streching = streching[:input_length]
TypeError: time_stretch() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
librosa.effects.time_stretch(streching.astype('float'), 1.1)
```

to this

```
librosa.effects.time_stretch(streching.astype('float'), rate=1.1)
```

because definition of this function has "*" which indicates that all the following parameters (rate in this case) must be specified

```
librosa.effects.time_stretch(y, *, rate, **kwargs)
```